# Toggle Visibility Of Multiple Content Chunks / Panes / Panels In ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, panel

I have an C# ASP.NET page (.aspx) which has two primary content regions: (1) a form with text fields (new Item) and (2) a grid control (list of Items). Very simply, the user can fill in the form to create a new Item, and they can see a list of Items to View/Edit/Delete. They click View and the page posts back to fill the form with Item data.

Currently they are both visible and are stacked (1) on top of (2). I would like to split this into two distinct panels, whose visibility can be toggled via a button or css tab etc.

When panel_1 is showing, panel_2 should not be (and vice-versa). Obviously I can achieve this easily directly with JavaScript (e.g. jQuery click event binding to a button or anchors etc.), but then it may get messy binding the grid control buttons events (View/Edit/Delete) to show the correct panel - i.e. fill in the form >> click Add Item >> show Item List panel (for example). I imagine I could pop some state params into the URL on post back and then bind that data to some local variables in order to know which panel should be showing, but I'm sure there is a better way.

In the future I may want to have 3/4/5 related content panels to toggle through, whether that's one form split over multiple panels, or one form and three different ways to display the data (list / graph / etc.).

Is there a clean ASP.NET (3.5) way to do this (i.e. wrap each content block in a control and maintain tight grip on UI)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASP.Net Ajax Accordion](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Accordion/Accordion.aspx) for this.

**ASP.Net Ajax Accordion:** The Accordion is a web control that allows you to provide multiple panes and display them one at a time. It is like having several CollapsiblePanels where only one can be expanded at a time. The Accordion is implemented as a web control that contains AccordionPane web controls. Each AccordionPane control has a template for its Header and its Content. We keep track of the selected pane so it stays visible across postbacks.

Also, you can try out:

[**jQuery UI Accordion:**](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) Click headers to expand/collapse content that is broken into logical sections, much like tabs. Optionally, toggle sections open/closed on mouseover.

**jQuery UI Accordion Sample code:**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
        amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
        odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
        purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
        velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
        suscipit faucibus urna.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
        Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
        ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
        lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
        et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
        faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
        mauris vel est.
        </p>
        <p>
        Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
        inceptos himenaeos.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, what would you advise regarding binding action buttons of the grid to showing the relevant panel? E.g., click 'View' button in grid control and the Item Form panel should be shown, while the Item List panel is hidden. Would you simply add click event handlers to the buttons with some JavaScript/jQuery? Additionally, when using the grid control's pagination, the page will post back and the default state will be restored (e.g. Item Form will be displayed) - would you recommend using URL query params to store some state, or server-side variables? Thanks.